Will moving miniconda to another directory with running slurm jobs?
I am working on a server cluster and my home directory started to exceed the size limit of 25GB. Is it possible to move miniconda and the .conda directory to the /scratch part of the cluster where I have a way higher memory limit without interrupting slurm jobs that are currently running and are using a conda enviorment? And would this interfere with activating the enviorment with source activate my_env_name in further jobs in the job array?

Some of the conda scripts for each environment are generated on creation and have hard-codes paths.  Moving the entire directory will break those links. It is better to create the environments in the new location.
You can set the default directory where environments are created and where packages are stored using:
conda config --prepend envs_dirs /path/to/some-dir/envs
conda config --prepend pkgs_dirs /path/to/some-dir/pkgs

